# Store data group by datetime column using pig

Tags: mapreduce, apache-pig

Say that I have the dataset like this

```
1, 3, 2015-03-25 11-15-13
1, 4, 2015-03-26 11-16-14
1, 4, 2015-03-25 11-16-15
1, 5, 2015-03-27 11-17-11
...
```

I want to store the data by datetime

so I will have the following output folders

```
2015-03-25/
2015-03-26/
2015-03-27/
...
```

How to do that with pig?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MultiStorage](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/MultiStorage.html) for this.

Use a `FOREACH GENERATE` to create a column that contains the date part that you are interested and then something like

```
STORE X INTO '/my/home/output' USING MultiStorage('/my/home/output','2');
```